# Jade.JS Img src not working

Tags: node.js, pug

I have no idea how to add img src next to a li so it will show the image next to the text and i wasted 30 minutes of my life trying to find a way, so please, i think this isnt a hard one for you guys, please tell me where/how to place and type it:

```
.container
    .row

        .ul.list-group

            .li
            .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S5

            .li
            .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S4

            .li
            .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S3

            .li
            .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S2

            .li
            .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S1

            .li
            .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S0
```

This is my current Jade Code, Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
.container
    .row
        ul.list-group
            li.list-group-item
                | Samsung Galaxy S5
                img(src='http//myUrl')
            li.list-group-item
                | Samsung Galaxy S4
                img(src='http//myUrl')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.container
    .row
        ul.list-group
            li
                img(src='url-to-page')
                .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S5

            li
                img(src='url-to-page')
                .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S4

            li
                img(src='url-to-page')
                .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S3

            li
                img(src='url-to-page')
                .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S2

            li
                img(src='url-to-page')
                .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S1

            li
                img(src='url-to-page')
                .list-group-item Samsung Galaxy S0
```

. is a class notation, and if you want HTML tags, use it without .

Comment: It does show the picture but it doesnt show it in the list-group, its seperated from it.